# Upper Bounded wildcards in Java

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard

I have two generic methods that calculate the sum of elements of a List. The signatures of the methods are

1. `double method1(List<? extends Number> list)` - Here I am using a wildcard.
2. `<U extends Number> double sumOfList1(List<U> list)` - Here there is a name for type parameter.

Is there any difference between these two or they're same in terms of functionality ? Using a type parameter name instead of wildcard has any advantages ?

```
public static double sumOfList(List<? extends Number> list) {
    double s = 0.0;
    for (Number n : list)
        s += n.doubleValue();
    return s;
}

 public static <U extends Number> double sumOfList1(List<U> list) {
    double s = 0.0;
    for (Number n : list)
        s += n.doubleValue();
    return s;
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

There is absolutely no difference, the purpose of declaring `U` is so that you can use it:

```
public static <U extends Number> void doSomething(List<U> list, Consumer<U> sink) {
    list.forEach(sink::accept)
}
```

This means that you don't care *what* `U` is, but it must extend from `Number`. What you do care about is that the `List` contains a type that is compatible with what the `Consumer` can accept.

---

Alternatively you can use `U` inside the method to declare new instances of the generic type:

```
public static <U extends Number> List<U> copy(List<U> list) {
    List<U> copy = new ArrayList<>();
    copy.addAll(list)
    return copy;
}
```

<sub>yes, I know, there are neater ways to do this - please treat it as an illustrative example</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not use `U` in this method, they have no difference.

Comment: I think it's worth pointing this out - you can use `U` in the second method.

Comment: @kabanus Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Because of type erasure the code being executed in the end is the same so there is no difference using one over the other.

Type erasure is explained [in this site](http://www.baeldung.com/java-type-erasure) like:

> The process of enforcing type constraints only at compile time and
>   discarding the element type information at runtime.